# Error parsing unicode date with strptime

Tags: python, datetime, unicode

I want to parse a date text with `strptime`

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

from time import strptime

date_text = '06月13日 星期五'
print strptime(date_text, '%m月%d日 %A')
```

and I got this error:

```
ValueError: time data '06\xe6\x9c\x8813\xe6\x97\xa5 \xe6\x98\x9f\xe6\x9c\x9f\xe4\xba\x94' does not match format '%m\xe6\x9c\x88%d\xe6\x97\xa5 %A'
```

Comment: Did you set the locale correctly? `%A` is locale dependent.

Comment: Note that the `coding` comment makes no difference here; you are creating byte strings, not Unicode values, no decoding takes place.

Comment: is there anything I can use to replace `%A`? actually I don't need that part of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%A` only parses weekdays in the currently configured locale; by default that's always the `C` locale and only english weekday names are recognised.

You'd have to set the locale with the [`locale` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale), but only do that for stand-alone programs used by one user at a time.

The other option is to not have `strptime` parse the weekday; you could look it up in your own mapping:

```
daymonth, weekday = date_text.split()
date = strptime(daymonth, '%m月%d日')
weekday = weekdays_dict[weekday]
```

or ignore `weekday` altogether; the same info is already contained in the month and day.

Either way, just the month and day portion can be parsed fine:

```
>>> from time import strptime
>>> date_text = '06月13日 星期五'
>>> strptime(date_text.split()[0], '%m月%d日')
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=164, tm_isdst=-1)
```